# Call override method from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have to call interface override method from another activity using button click.In GridActivity class I have using the image button.

If I click this button I need to call the other activity interface override method.

**GridActivity3.java:**

```
public class GridActivity3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 ImageButton btn_home;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid3);

        btn_home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_home);

        btn_home.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_home:

     break;

     }
    }
   }
```

**ArticleSelectedListener:**

```
public interface ArticleSelectedListener {

    public void onArticleSelected(final int position, final String content);
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ArticleSelectedListener {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

   @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position, String content)
    {
        if(position==0)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            HomeFirstFragment newFragment = new HomeFirstFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
     }
```

I don't know how to call the interface method from another activity on button click.Anyone can help me with this.Thank You.

Comment: what u ment by interface override method? OnArticleSelected()?

Comment: @RishadAppat yes OnArticleSelected() method.If I call that then only I can switch to that activity on button click.

Comment: you meant, u want to go to the MainActivity from GridActivity on button click?

Comment: @RishadAppat no.If I call the onArticleSelectedListener with position 0. I can get into `HomeFirstFragment`.That means GridActivity->HomeFirstFragment with the help of MainActiivty interface method

Comment: alryt... the position is 0, what about the content? Since On article selected have two parameters....

Comment: @RishadAppat Let me call the content like this? `onArticleSelected(0, "Home");`

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, create a public method as follows...

```
public void articleSelected(int position, String content)
  {
     if(position==0)
    {
        action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        HomeFirstFragment newFragment = new HomeFirstFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
  }
```

Then in the Main activity, replace the code inside OnArticle selected with the following...

```
articleSelected(position,content);
```

Then use the same method to call from GridActivity...

```
     MainActivity main= new MainActivity();
     main.articleSelected(0,"Home");
```

Comment: where I have to change this one : `articleSelected(position,content);`

Comment: inside @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position, String content)
    {                                     }                          remove all other codes inside that method...

Comment: yes I did that.Now I am getting null pointer exception at this line `action_bar_hometext.setText(content);` [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/hsasvbj099gjsalapa3eq)